# Any site for booking travel tickets for visa without paying?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, europe

I need to submit a travel itinerary in order to apply for Schengen Visa. Is there any site (like Expedia, Orbitz, etc) where I can book a round-trip flights for a week? In Orbitz, I can do it for 24 hours but to me that's too tight schedule. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean simulate a booking for visa purpose with no intent to actually buy the tickets ?

Comment: These days, most airlines will only hold a seat for a day. When you reserve a seat, you both deny the airline the possibility of selling it and deny another traveler the possibility of reserving it; no airline has an interest in making it easy for you to reserve a seat you don't plan to use.

Comment: The usual solution to this dilemma is to book a fully refundable ticket, and then cancel it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put AAdvantage award seats on hold for five days at www.aa.com. You do not actually need to have any miles, signing up for an account is free. The availability of anytime awards are quite good because they are hideously expensive.